# Multiple git-annex repos on one drive

Tags: git, storage, git-annex

I *think* that this is possible with git-annex as it exists right now, but I'm just looking to make sure.

Right now I have a file tree that looks something like this:

```
+ knowledge
+ media
+ ...
```

And this goes on and on.

**I'd like to create a git-annex repo for each top level folder.** This means that there will be about 5 *different* git-annex repos on one external hard drive. Each of those repos would have a remote on my local machine, a flash drive, and another external hard drive.

Before I go about moving these hundreds of gigabytes of files around, I just wanted to make sure that nothing *should* blow up if `cd` into each of those top level directories on my external drive and initialize a git annex repo inside each of them. After that I would add the contents of each folder to their respective annex formed in that folder. At the end of the day, if I did this, would I be left with each of those directories converted into their own git-annex repo, with each repor containing all of the files that used to be in that respective directory?

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple, fully separate annexes.

You can even use the [git-annex Webapp](http://git-annex.branchable.com/design/assistant/webapp/) with this setup.